# Facebook email claim is not sent to Azure ACS

Tags: facebook, azure, sharepoint, acs, claims

I am trying to integrate Facebook login to my SharePoint 2013 site. I am using Azure ACS and have included both Facebook and Google as Identity Providers.
When logging in with Google, everything works just as expected.

But when I log in via Facebook, I am just redirected back to the login page. Troubleshooting this issue with Fiddler and the debug tool at developer.facebook.com/tools/debug led me to the conclusion that the token sent from Facebook to ACS is not including the email claim.
The claims sent are nameidentifier and name.

Facebook IP in Azure is setup to request email (which is default), but no email claim is received.

Does anyone know if facebook have changed anything recently? Do I have to do anything specific in my facebook app? I find it very strange that noone else has reported this issue. There must be several websites out there that uses facebook as an identity provider, relying on users email as claim.

I have followed the following articles for the setup:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/meacoex/archive/2013/12/25/authenticate-your-sharepoint-website-users-with-facebook.aspx

http://blogs.technet.com/b/meamcs/archive/2013/06/01/use-facebook-as-an-identity-provider-for-sharepoint-2013-part-1.aspx

Any help in this issue is greatly appreciated.
/BR Mathias

Comment: A recent change with API v2.4 is that the number of fields that the different endpoints return was reduced, and additional fields now have to be specifically asked for, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4_changes, “declarative fields”.

Comment: Thank you for the info! Do you know if its possible to change API version on the facebook app?

Comment: App dashboard will show you the oldest API version your app can use, depending on when your app was created; going “lower” than that is not possible. Apart from that, the API version is specified in the URL when you make API requests. (The common SDKs allow to specify the API version on initialization, so that the version specifier in all URLs will be set automatically.)

Comment: I guess its not much I can do then. I'll throw the ball over to Azure product group. Thank you for the help @CBroe!